# How to sum hh:mm:ss with specific data in another column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to get the duration but with the active column condition = yes.

I already try with SUMIF function but the result was 00:00:00.

[image: This is my example table]

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  If you have tried something with `SUMIF` then post that. Please review site guidelines on [ask] and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then [edit] your post instead of adding information in a comment.

Comment: Can you post the actual formula you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Using `SUMIF` works fine.  In my simple example:

[image]

I used the following `SUMIF`:

- `=SUMIF(A1:A4,"yes",B1:B4)`

Comment: If I was SUM-ming all fields, yes.  However, that's not what OP asked.  OP asked to SUM only the fields with "yes" next to them, which I did using SUMIF.

Comment: ,,  yes U r write, I've added extra cell ☺

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**How it works:**

- I'm assuming your data in Range `A2:B10`.
- Select `B1:B10` and apply Time Format 
  `HH:MM:SS`.
- Enter this Formula in `B11`.

`=SUMIF(A2:A10,"Yes",B2:B10)`

- **Apply Time Format `[HH]:MM:SS` on Cell 
  `B11`.**
- *Adjust cell reference in the Formula as 
  needed*.